# Are sun glasses and sunglasses both correct?

Tags: orthography

My questions are: the words sun glasses mean the same as sunglasses? And both are grammatically correct? And both are still in use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are correct, but "sunglasses" is the vastly more common version in the USA.  I'm not sure what the preferred UK/international usage is.

Comment: The preferred UK usage is also "sunglasses".

Answer (score 1):

I've checked a number of dictionaries, and they all show "sunglasses", with no alternative spelling. If I saw "sun glasses", I would expect it to mean something different.

Comment: I just simply searched in the english wikipedia about sun glasses (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sunglasses), it says "Sunglasses or sun glasses (informally called shades or sunnies; more names below)"

Comment: Ok. Have you found any dictionaries that show that spelling?